# Triplanar texturing in glsl

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, hlsl

I followed a paper called "GPU Based Algorithms for Terrain Texturing" and it says the following:

> The main algorithm to apply triplanar texturing is fairly simple.
>   First, we check whether the slope is relatively large in the same way
>   that we do with slope based texturing. These regions with high slope
>   will be the only regions aected by the algorithm. We then check what
>   the larger component of the normal is, out of x and z. If x is the
>   larger component, we use the geometry z coordinate as the texture
>   coordinate s, and the geometry y coordinate as the texture coordinate
>   t. If z is the larger component, we use the geometry x coordinate as
>   the texture coordinate s, and the geometry y coordinate as the texture
>   coordinate t.

So I tried to implement it. This is my heightmap:
[image: heightmap]

Note that I added white lines in the borders just for the experiment, so now I have maximum-height walls surrounding my map.

Now following the articles, here's the implementation in the vertex shader:

```
#version 430

uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 CameraMatrix;

uniform vec3 scale;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 fsVertex;
out vec3 fsNormal;
out vec2 fsUvs;

void main()
{
    fsVertex = vertex;
    fsNormal = normalize(normal);

    if(fsNormal.y < 0.75) {
        if(fsNormal.x > fsNormal.z)
            fsUvs = vertex.zy * scale.zy;
        else
            fsUvs = vertex.xy * scale.xy;
    }
    else
        fsUvs = vertex.xz * scale.xz;

    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * CameraMatrix * vec4(vertex * scale, 1.0);
}
```

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/UzAiN05e) the fragment shader, if it helps.

This is what I get:
[image: outcome]

[Here's a further look](http://s11.postimg.org/qgxr5zjxv/far.png), for proportion.
The top and left walls (of the heightmap) are rendered ok, and the bottom and right walls still suffer from stretching. I also get these weird stretches spots next to the beginning of the walls.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if the normal's x or z coordinate are longer, you should use the `abs` function:

```
if(abs(fsNormal.x) > abs(fsNormal.z))
```

Furthermore, the `y > 0.75` seems like a coarse approximation, which is probably good enough in most cases. Actually, the maximum of `abs(x), abs(y), abs(z)` gives you the correct plane.

Comment: Why is it a coarse approximation? And thanks, that did the trick for most of the issue, but I still get these weird incorrectly sampled textures in some places (labeled "What is this?" in the image I posted). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Coarse approximation means that `y` can be the maximum without fulfilling `y>0.75`. E.g. for the normal vector `(0.5, 0.71, 0.5)`, `y` is maximum but less than `0.75`.  For the red lines, I don't know what you mean. The question "what is this?" has the answer "a red line" but I doubt that you meant this. If there are discontinuities, you might want to blend textures if two or more components are near maximum.

Comment: I check if vertex.y is above 0.75 so then it will use the snow texture. What other way do you purpose? Also if you view the image in its full size you will see that the texture screws up there. Im new to terrain rendering so if you could link me to some learning sources it would be great

Answer (score -1):

Here is a DX11/HLSL implementation i used. GLSL conversion should be easy.
With the exponent value you can tune the blending speed at the borders. i used something like 3.

```
float3 SampleTriplanarTexture(Texture2D<float4> tex1, Texture2D<float4> tex2, Texture2D<float4> tex3, float3 normal, float3 pos, float exponent)
{
    //triplanar projection
    float mXY = pow(abs(normal.z), exponent);
    float mXZ = pow(abs(normal.y), exponent);
    float mYZ = pow(abs(normal.x), exponent);
    float total = 1.0f / (mXY + mXZ + mYZ);
    mXY *= total;
    mXZ *= total;
    mYZ *= total;

    return  tex1.SampleLevel(linearSampler2, pos.xz, 0) * mXZ +
            tex2.SampleLevel(linearSampler2, pos.xy, 0) * mXY +
            tex3.SampleLevel(linearSampler2, pos.yz, 0) * mYZ;
}
```